# Using Lookup in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, lookup

I am getting an error when trying to use this lookup formula to find the last cell with a value and enter it in another cell this is the formula I'm using in excel but it is giving me an error in google sheets saying "Did not find value 2 in lookup evaluation"

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D1:AJ1 <> ""),D1:AJ1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=INDEX(D1:AJ1,MAX(COLUMN(D1:AJ1)*(D1:AJ1<>"")))
```

If you the values you want to return are text, you can also try

```
=lookup("zzz", D1:AJ1)
```

or, if numeric:

```
=lookup(1E+100,D1:AJ1)
```